# How to find how many words with 10 or more letters are in a file

Tags: linux, shell, command-line

I want to know how many words with 10 or more letters are in a document without using regex. (this is for a school work and it is one of the contraints)

I have been trying multiple thing but really havent been getting there,

I tried using vim with the command `:g/..........//ng` ; but it wasn't showing the number of lines and I didn't find how

Also I tried getting how many words are in my document with `wc -w` and then using `cut -c-9`  and re `>` to redirect it to another document and `wc -w NEWDOC` and substract the 2 but it did not work

also tried with `perl` and `awk`, I'm a begginer so I'm kinda lost with all this.

Comment: To be honest i'm really lost, I tried putting the document in vim and using :g/..........//ng ; Also tried with perl and awk bt haven't really gotten anywhere

Comment: Can't use regex because it's a school work and one of the contraints is to not use them

Comment: I was thinkink about something like, how many words have caracters after the 10th position

Comment: I'll do it  thanks for telling me

Comment: Can you provide sample data and the expected output?

Comment: It's a dictionnary type of document so its one word per line and the expected output would be a number that is the number of words in the documents with 10 or more caracters

Comment: The `/........../` part of `g/..........//ng` is a regex. Nearly all solutions I can think of either use a regex (with grep) or require an actual programming or scripting language. Can you use globbing?

Comment: Yeah, I realized afterwards that /........../ and g/..........//ng are regex

Comment: from my understanding awk `'length>=10{s++}END{print s}'  inputfile` should work I feel like the program that checks the answers might have a bug and it should be the right answer. We have to return a document explaining the  commands and not their results in itself so i'll explain it and give the results and should have the points.  Thank you very much for the help Quasimodo